# Androidアプリのエラー処理

Tags: android, java, android-layout, xml

少しエラーが解決したので修正しました．
そこで，「ListView は解決できないか、フィールドではありません」
を解決したいです．
どうすれば良いでしょうか？
以下詳細．

Androidアプリのエラー処理について質問です．
Androidアプリに関してあまりよく分かってません．コードを以下に記載しますので，どこがどうおかしいか等教えてください．
また，「@Override」が何のために必要なのか等も教えてほしいです．

修正後のエラー

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
```

↑の部分で
ListView は解決できないか、フィールドではありません
というエラーが表示されます
また，

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DAYS);
```

↑の部分で
この行に複数マーカーがあります
    - ListAdapter を型に解決でき
     ません
    - ArrayAdapter を型に解決で
     きません
というエラーが表示されます．
対処方法が分かる方お願いします．

```
package com.example.recip;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);

        //adapterの作成
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, DAYS);
        //Adapterの設定
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    //ListViewに表示させる文字列
    private static final String[] DAYS = new String[] {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

またXMLファイルのコードも記載します．

```
    <RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.recip.MainActivity" >

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ボタンの配置" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="gazou" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `RelativeLayoutxmlns:android` タイプミスでなければ 次のように`RelativeLayout xmlns:android` スペースが必要のように思います。

Answer (score 2):

使用しているIDEはeclipseですよね？

> ListView は解決できないか、フィールドではありません

これは、`findViewById(R.id.ListView)`の部分の`R.id.ListView`という名前が見つからないというエラーです。

`XML`の`@+id/ListView`の`ListView`と、`findViewById(R.id.ListView)`の`ListView`は大文字小文字を含めて同じでないとダメです。
ソースを見た感じでは、上記のエラーは出なさそうです。eclipseではjavaファイルやxmlファイルを保存(ctrl+s)したときにコンパイルを行っています。
xmlファイルは保存していますか？

> ListAdapter を型に解決できません
>   ArrayAdapter を型に解決できません

これは、`import`文が指定されていないためだと思います。
`eclipse`では`import`文は自動で追加してくれません。
`ctrl+shift+O`キーで`import`文を追加(編成)してくれます。

> また，「@Override」が何のために必要なのか等も教えてほしいです．

メソッドやフィールドの上に@hogehogeとあるのはアノテーションと呼ばれるものです。
`@Override`は、そのメソッドがオーバーライドしているということを示しています。
このアノテーションに関しては、「このメソッドはオーバーライドしているメソッドです」というのをコンパイラに教えてあげているだけですので、消してもエラーにはなりませんし、動作も変わりありません。
しかし、メソッド名などを打ち間違えたときに、コンパイラでエラーを出してくれるため消さずに残しておきましょう。
Javaの入門書を１冊読んでおくといいかもしれません。